# WCF Service with entity framework error with more than table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I use Visual Studio 2013 and I want to create a WCF Service with Entity Framework to get access to a database.

I created a simple database with SQL Server Express (for example, 2 tables: `User` and `Formation`, with `IdUser` as a foreign key in the `Formation` table)

I created a new WCF service and added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (`.edmx`) linked to my database.
I also created a method to return all my `Users`. When I try the method in the WCF Test User or in a console application, I get a `CommunicationException` error.

But it works correctly if I remove the foreign key in my User table...

My `GetUsers()` method:

```
public List<User> GetUsers()
{
   MyContext db= new MyContext();
   var s =(from w in db.User
           select w).ToList();
   return s;  
}
```

Comment: If it works when you remove the foreign key, it means there's something going on in EF. That `CommunicationException` is just a wrapper for the actual EF/SQL exception thrown. Set a breakpoint on the server side and see what the actual error (`InnerException`?) says.

Comment: Setting up WCF tracing in the Web.config should be the first thing you do with a new WCF service project. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%c28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the classes generated by the EF will not be serialized with WCF therefore you need to create another class that would be [DataContract] and datamenber and then send the object of that class to return

please take a look at this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127395/Implementing-a-WCF-Service-with-Entity-Framework